# After WL upgrade , Destination unreachable

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, weblogic12c

Getting the below error after upgrading to WL 12.3

We have two different WL 12.3 instances on same machine (illd120).

Server 1 - illd120:2841 , and SSL listen port set to 9041.

Server 2 - illd120:4541  .

While doing call from Server1 to Server2  we use t3s protocol (t3s://illd120:9041) and getting the below error.

If we switch to t3 (non-SSL) connectivity is working fine.

> **Throws: javax.naming.CommunicationException: t3s://illd120:9041: Destination 10.110.110.117, 9041 unreachable; nested exception is:**
>           javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://illd120:9041: Destination 10.110.110.117,
>   9041 unreachable; nested exception is:
>           javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem; No available router to destination]

I think its related to proxy configuration.

I tried to exclude the machine name (illd120) from proxy but still the same.

please advise what else I can try.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have one managed server running on illd120:9041 and the other managed server running on what port? Both servers can't run on 9041... Also, what does the remote call look like? If they are running on the same host you should not have any problems. Are you using the demo certs?

Comment: 2 Servers , running on same machine. Each use different port . the 9041 is port which defined in server 1 for SSL connections. Yes i use the demo certs. Which part confused you ? i will modify it....

Comment: Can you edit it to show what your `Server 1 = host:port` and `Server 2 = host:port` are set to? What does the remote call look like? Have you set the `listen-address` for each server inside the admin console?

Comment: I updated the details. not sure what you mean when asking how call looks. Its just RMI call.